# Cannot load string from XML (SimpleXML)

Tags: php, xml

I use PHP function **simplexml_load_string** and trying to get Data from XML Data
But it look like i cannot get anything from this xml data

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [attribute] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => uname [value] => admin ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => playerlevel [value] => 1 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [name] => sessionid [value] => i9vfgvqo30c2kk2g57avmd0t ) ) )
```

This is my code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($request->body);
```

I have try with echo $xml[0], $xml[0]->value, $xml[1], It cannot get anything from this xml data.

Comment: XMLElements are not arrays. `$xml[0]` is not going to be set unless `$request->body` contained '<0>' tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to derive the correct call from the XML rather than a `print_r()` from the SimpleXMLObject (which makes heavy use of `Iterator` and `ArrayAccess`)

If the (reverse engineered) XML is something along

```
<root>
    <attribute>
        <name>uname</name>
        <value>admin</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>playerlevel</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>sessionid</name>
        <value>i9vfgvqo30c2kk2g57avmd0t</value>
    </attribute>
</root>
```

then the call sequence for the first `<root><attribute><name>` is

```
$xml->attribute[0]->name
```